# Best designed android ROM for LG Optimus 2X P990

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, 2.3-gingerbread, 4.1-jelly-bean, lg-optimus-2x

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device)

I am really busy trying to find a ROM that fits my personality for my LG Optimus 2X P990. I have used CM7. CM9, CM10 and MIUI. I really like MIUI v4 and above, but i haven't found any MIUI v4 ROM that is stable enough for daily basis. I really like ROMS that has kind of flat buttons as seen in the metro UI and ics and above roms. I like it professional with not like big really graphic intense UI's. I have searched a lot, and i have looked into the Prada rom for the LG Optimus 2X, but i couldn't find a download link. Do anyone of you have a ROM that is fast, professional and stable enough for daily basis? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, we don't do recommendations here (see the [FAQ]); the linked duplicate is the closest we get.  We find that objective questions work best on Stack Exchange and don't devolve into opinionated popularity contests.  Feel free to ask any other questions you might have that would be a better fit!

Answer (score 0):

Try the original rom...
I came back to the original rom after a long spell on all kinds of developer mods, and was pleasantly surprised. I am on V20g and it is flying...I have yet to encounter any problems.
MIUI and CM are all clever, but they all come with errors one way or another.
If you need a rooted one with CWM then you could try this:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=34379632&postcount=267

Comment: I have tried the stock ones and that one as well but the gb lg feeling is good, but not just 100% me. I have gone a bit in and out of ics from lg though. I think i'll be running that for a couple of days and see if i like it. Thanks